# Installing the .ipa programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios

I have a requirement to install an .ipa file programmatically. As far as my understanding apple doesn't allow us to install it because of security reasons. 
I tried putting an.ipa in my resource folder and opening it, but it doesn't allow me to do so. Is there a way to install this .ipa programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to install the .ipa programmatically from an app that is available on the app store.

The only way to install an .ipa (which actually is a zip folder containing all the assets and bytecode your app needs to run) other than the app store is to have an enterprise account and distribute your app with a provisioning profile to users within your organization. But even this way you just install your app's ipa outside the app store, you cannot make your app to install another .ipa to the user's device.